# How to add last element of an array to another array in vue/Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, vue.js

I have a vue application where I am trying to push the last elemnt of an array to another array each time a specific button is clicked. I tried this approach:

```
  generateGroup(){
          this.$refs.addGroupModal.generateGroup() 
   this.meetingsArray.push(this.meetingArrayBackend[this.meetingArrayBackend.length - 1])
        },
```

this is the method which is called from my $ref:

```
generateGroup(){
    var pageURL = window.location.href;
    var lastURLSegment = pageURL.substr(pageURL.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
     const newMeeting = {meetingUrl: "", meetingName: "", date: this.selectedDate, startTime: "", endTime: ""};
      newMeeting.meetingUrl = "https://jitsi.zim.uni-due.de/" + this.randomUrlIdGenerator().toString()
      newMeeting.meetingName = lastURLSegment
    this.model.forEach((model, i) => {
      const key = `participant${i + 1}`;
      newMeeting[key] = model.voterUniqueName;
      newMeeting.startTime = model.startTime;
      newMeeting.endTime = model.endTime
    })
    this.newGroup = [],
    this.finalMeetingArray.push(newMeeting)
    setTimeout(() => { this.newGroup.push(newMeeting) })
    this.newGroup = []
    this.selectedDate = ""
    this.model = []
```

But the problem is it only works if I have more than one element inside meetingArrayBackend. But I want to add everytime on button click the last element of that array to the inside meetingArray

Maybe the error is because I am sync ing the meetingArrayBackend with a prop from another component like this:

```
<AddGroupsModal :new-group.sync="meetingArrayBackend" ref="addGroupModal"/>
```

And use it to display like this:

```
<v-col>
        <v-data-table
            :headers="headers"
            :items="meetingArrayBackend"
            :items-per-page="3"
            class="elevation-1"
        ></v-data-table>
      </v-col>
```

Comment: It's unclear what is the problem with the code. `arr.[arr.length - 1]` is a legit way the last element can be accessed. *it only works if I have more than one element inside meetingArrayBackend* - it works with 1 element too.

Comment: If I only have one element for some reason it is shown as undefined eventhough in my table it is visible

Comment: The question is XY problem. You misidentified the cause. `arr.[arr.length - 1]` works in a very straightforward way. That it's undefined probably means that length is 0 at some point. If you have problems with how JS works with arrays, consider asking JS question without Vue part. Any way, consider providing https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve .